# How do i make it so my bot purges after a command was triggered?

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

I wanna make my bot purge after a person has triggered a command so like for example whenever a person say like "Hello" (the command that i have it set to) my bot will immediately purge 100 or whatever amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.bulkDelete()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete) for that.

> ```js
> // Bulk delete messages
> channel.bulkDelete(5)
>   .then(messages => console.log(`Bulk deleted ${messages.size} messages`))
>   .catch(console.error);
> ```